# Why is dnsmasq putting my router IP in /etc/resolv.conf instead of 127.0.0.1?

Tags: dns, dnsmasq, resolv.conf

I'm having DNS resolution issues in various contexts which appear to trace back to my networking configuration.

I'm running just the `dnsmasq-base` installation of `dnsmasq` on two Linux installations (Lubuntu 12.04 and 12.10). I haven't done anything in particular to configure `dnsmasq`, but I think some other changes I made previously may have lead to an incorrect configuration when upgrading.

The working configuration on machine 'A' running 12.04 sets `/etc/resolv.conf` to use 127.0.1.1 (which in `/etc/hosts` is set to `$HOSTNAME`) On machine 'B' where certain applications such as OpenVPN experience DNS resolution issues, `/etc/resolv.conf` is set to 192.168.1.1, which is my gateway IP. Only certain applications are affected. Web-browsing, for example, works just fine.

Any idea if this difference is the cause of the DNS resolution issues, and why 'B' is behaving differently?

Edits:

Both 'A' and 'B' are running `dnsmasq`, both are using DHCP to get DNS configuration, and I'm only using dnsmasq for DNS.

There is no `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` file. I understand that this is normal when running just `dnsmasq-base`.

The contents of `/etc/resolvconf` on the two machines appear to be identical. No extraneous/missing files.

Sorry I can't be more specific about the nature of the problem. "DNS resolution issue" was the end-point of my discussion with technical support at my VPN provider.

Comment: If browsing works DNS can't be the problem. No matter what service is querying the nameserver, they do it in the same manner.  Are both A and B using DHCP to get their network configured?

Comment: On which machine, 'A' or 'B', does dnsmasq run?  Does dnsmasq do DHCP as well as DNS?  What is the value of the "resolv-file" parameter in dnsmasq.conf?

Comment: Yes, it is unbelievable that the commercial (!) makes of Ubuntu would do that to their distribution, but they messed up their DNS. Check your machine B for files in `/etc/resolvconf/` and see if any appears like it may be causing your problem.

Comment: dnsmasq is considered to be a bug by some sysadmins and you don't need it. It adds one more level of indirection in what is already a torturous resolution chain. You can kill the process with no visible adverse effect and may want to disable it permanently. dhclient will fill all your DHCP needs.

Answer (score 1):

On machine B, if `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` contains `dns=dnsmasq` then `resolv.conf` should contain only one "nameserver" line, namely `nameserver 127.0.1.1`. 127.0.1.1 is the address where the NetworkManager-controlled local forwarding nameserver listens. NetworkManager gives that nameserver forwarding addresses to use.

Try running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` on machine B. This will restore the needed symbolic link from `/etc/resolv.conf` to `../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`.

Are you running a third-party VPN client? Such clients are known to clobber `/etc/resolv.conf` and not to restore it when they exit. You may have to do `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` every time you stop such a client.

Another thing to try is: comment out `dns=dnsmasq` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and then reboot. This disables the NetworkManager-controlled local forwarding nameserver which has some known issues.